# How to do a Selective Cartesian Product of a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am trying to get a list of lists that represent all possible ordered pairs from an existing list of lists.

```
import itertools
list_of_lists=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7],[8, 9],[10, 11],[12, 13],[14, 15],[16, 17],[18, 19],[20, 21],[22, 23],[24, 25],[26, 27],[28, 29],[30, 31],[32, 33],[34, 35],[36, 37],[38],[39]]
```

Ideally, we would just use itertools.product in order to get that list of ordered pairs.

```
scenarios_list=list(itertools.product(*list_of_lists))
```

However, if I were to do this for a larger list of lists I would get a memory error and so this solution is not scalable for larger lists of lists where there could be numerous different sets of ordered pairs.

So, is there a way to set up a process where we could iterate through these ordered pairs as they are produced where before appending the list to another list, we could test if the list satisfies a certain criteria (for example testing whether there are a certain number of even numbers, sum of list cannot be equal to the maximum, etc). If the criteria is not satisfied then the ordered pair would not be appended and thus not unnecessarily suck up memory when there are only certain ordered pairs that we care about.

Comment: "iterate through these ordered pairs as they are produced" - this is exactly what `itertools.product(*list_of_lists)` lets you do. There's no need to store all combinations in a list.

Comment: `itertools.product` is a generator, not just an array. So you can iterate through it, and it won't create the whole array when called first time - won't require all of the memory

Comment: Filtering the result of `itertools.product` (without turning it into a list first) is the simple way to go about it. But if it generates that many products and you'll end up rejecting a lot of them, it's better to roll your own recursive generator which prunes products the moment they are guaranteed to not meet the criteria. For example, if you require at most three even numbers and you already have the partial (0, 5, 6, 8), any of (10, 12, 14, 16, etc), will be prematurely rejected, saving you lots of time.

Comment: @Reti43 could you provide an example answer for using a custom generator? That would  be very helpful.

Comment: What are your selection criteria?

Comment: Combinatorics get out of hand quickly. You are almost always better off trying to put these restrictions into the generation process instead of overgenerating and filtering later.

Comment: @Reti43 I just want to see an example using any selection criteria

Comment: @user2390182 Can you provide an example using this data?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a recursive base implementation of `product`:

```
def product(*lsts):
    if not lsts:
        yield ()
        return
    first_lst, *rest = lsts
    for element in first_lst:
        for rec_p in product(*rest):
            p = (element,) + rec_p
            yield p

[*product([1, 2], [3, 4, 5])]
# [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Now, you could augment that with a condition by which you filter any `p` not meeting it:

```
def product(*lsts, condition=None):
    if condition is None:
        condition = lambda tpl: True
    if not lsts:
        yield ()
        return
    first_lst, *rest = lsts
    for element in first_lst:
        for rec_p in product(*rest, condition=condition):
            p = (element,) + rec_p
            if condition(p):  # stop overproduction right where it happens
                yield p
```

Now you can - for instance - restrict to only even elements:

```
[*product([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], condition=lambda tpl: not any(x%2 for x in tpl))]
# [(2, 4)]
```